# Acumatica - adding a new field to the inventory history inquiry sceen

Tags: acumatica

I am running into an issue trying to add a new column to the IN.40.50.00 (inventory transaction history) screen.  I want to add the PO number to the inquiry screen.  I believe I have implemented the search correctly, but I keep getting the following error:
\App_RuntimeCode\PX_Objects_IN_InventoryTranHistEnqResult_extensions.cs(27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'docRefNbr' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my search:
[PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2, And>>>, Where>>>))]

Comment: Here is my search:
[PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<PX.Objects.PO.POReceiptLine.pONbr, InnerJoin<INTran, On<INTran.pOReceiptNbr, 
Equal<PX.Objects.PO.POReceiptLine.receiptNbr>, And<INTran.pOReceiptLineNbr, Equal<PX.Objects.PO.POReceiptLine.lineNbr>>>>, Where<INTran.refNbr, Equal<Current<docRefNbr>>>>))]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the DAC name before the docRefNbr in the last Current clause and give it a try:

```
[PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<
                PX.Objects.PO.POReceiptLine.pONbr, 
                InnerJoin<INTran, 
                    On<INTran.pOReceiptNbr, Equal<PX.Objects.PO.POReceiptLine.receiptNbr>, 
                    And<INTran.pOReceiptLineNbr, Equal<PX.Objects.PO.POReceiptLine.lineNbr>>>>, 
                Where<INTran.refNbr, Equal<Current<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.docRefNbr>>>>))]
```